# Non-UI thread, UI access

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

It is well-known that you cannot update the UI from any other thread other than the UI thread.

However, I just discovered some code, that gets a value of a listview virtualsize, from a non-UI thread without Exception.

So really my question is:
what interaction can you have with the UI from a non-UI thread?

Thank you
Theo

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but reading a value from another thread does not update anything, so it is possible. If you need to ***change*** something in the UI, you need to synchronize your action with the UI thread, using an UI dispatcher for instance, if available.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not you're updating. What does matter is that the UI thread may be updating the data you are trying to read, and then you get corrupt data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Because it works without throwing an exception, does not mean you should do this.**

The problem is that besides the `Invoke` requirement for methods that update the UI, these controls also do not support multi threading. That means that when the UI thread updates the data while you are retrieving it, you do get corrupt data.

Comment: Nope. Specifically because the documentation explicitly notes that these objects do not support multi threading (see the 'Thread Safety
' chapter of the classes), they do not make any effort to lock these things.

Comment: Answer given, as you replied first!

Answer (score 5):

The specific rule is that you cannot call a Windows API function that uses the Handle of a window.  It isn't exactly obvious whether or not using a property or calling a method of a control will end up making such an API call.  The MSDN docs lists only 4 of them as always safe to use: InvokeRequired, Invoke(), BeginInvoke() and CreateGraphics().

But yes, sometimes a property value is available and doesn't require an API call.  The Text property is a good example.  It is cached because it is used so often.  *Reading* the Text property doesn't generate an exception, you just get cached value.  But *writing* the Text property goes kaboom, updating the text on the screen requires an API call.  ListView.VirtualSize works the exact same way.

You don't get the exception but it is still not kosher.  After all, the UI thread might change the Text property as well, a microsecond later.  You'll get a stale value, a classic threading problem known as a race condition.

Comment: So essentially, you can get away with it, but, don't!

Comment: Write your code so you don't have to get away with it.  Use the thread only to collect the data, updating the UI with it should happen on the UI thread.  This comes pretty naturally when you use a BackgroundWorker.